# String.split() method doesn't work in eclipse oxygen version 4.7.0M2

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

String.split() method doesn't work in Eclipse Oxygen version 4.7.0M2
I have prepared a simple code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int T = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
    while(T > 0)
    {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        String inp = System.console().readLine();
        String[] inp =   inp.split("\\s+");
        T--;
    }
}
```

[image: Please find the Screenshot of the error]

split() showing error in IDE. I am using JRE 1.8. The same function work correctly with the same JRE in Eclipse Luna.
Please anyone help me to understand the exact problem.

Comment: "The same function work correctly with the same jre in eclipse Luna" I find this very hard to believe. If that is the case, it is a pretty fundamental bug.

Comment: It's compilation error, not possible on eclipse luna you didn't get  this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined two variables with the same name: String inp and String[] inp.
Give the string array a different name.

Comment: Yes.Thank You for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you try to invoke split method on a string array. Try to rename the string array and it will work!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int T = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
    while(T > 0)
    {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        String inp = System.console().readLine();
        String[] inp2 =   inp.split("\\s+");
        T--;
    }
}
```